# Need to load excel data into sql, then I need to use sql data for forecasting

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, postgresql, forecasting

- I am interning at a company and they want to load their excel data (with formulas) into SQL. There are 2 types of excel sheets. The first ones contain their initial budgets, while the second ones contain the total expenses by each department. After loading the data into SQL, they want to use the first sheets (containing their budgets) to forecast, and compare them to the second sheets (containing the real expenses).
- I was thinking about saving the data as csv (not sure if the formulas will let me do it). Then pulling everything into MYSQL using Workbench. After that, I am not sure on how to forecast with the data from the first sheet for comparison.
- I am not sure if I should use MySQL and Workbench due to licensing issues, I though about using PostgreSQL and pgAdmin

ny ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your question mentions mysql as your database engine. It's best to also include `mysql` as a tag so you get adequate answers.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if using MySQL is convenient, though

Comment: If the data is static you won't need the formulae. If you do need them then you will have to refactor them into SQL so the relationships hold in the DB.

Comment: The data is static. However, I need to compare the initial budgets to the actual expenses.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading the data into SQL"? SQL is a language, not a software product.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help:-

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/file_name.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' /* if applicable */
ENCLOSED BY '"' /* if applicable */
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS; /* IF you want to exclude header row */
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing that task really often too. I found a lot of great conversion applications who help you to convert your Excel sheets to SQL or MySQL Databases and nearly any Database-Management-Application has such a tool too. So you could search for that in your management-studio.

Otherwise I recommend you to read this tutorial by MySQL itself, where they show how to convert a Excelsheet to a MySQL Database:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html

Other converters:
https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-excel-to-mysql-online;
https://sqlizer.io/#/;

Then you have to simply import them into your database by using the standard Database import tool.